# Fastest Way to Populate a Pandas DataFrame When Order Matters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm building some basic support code for possibly large data grabs from an API.  The results come out as a dict for each index value. i.e.

```
[(index0, {col3:val3, col0:val0, col12:val12, ...}), (index1,{...}), ...]
```

However, while the indices come out in order the columns do not.  Also, not all columns will necessarily be available for all indices.

It is important the columns end up in the correct order `col_list = [col0, col1, ...]` as well as the indicies `index_list = [index0, index1, ...]`

My inclination is to just predefine the dataframe

```
df = DataFrame(index=index_list, columns=col_list)
```

and just assign the data by `df.loc[idx, col] = val` which might be the fastest way if the data was sparse.  However, the data is almost certainly dense.

Are there any alternate constructors that would be significantly faster?

Comment: Have you tried using `pd.read_json` ? (is this valid json?) Please give an actual/pretend but complete snippet to play with.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not json.  The API is non-standard and a bit wonky which is why I tried to be a bit vague above.  Think about it as the API gives the index0 then a dict of cols/vals and then index1 and its dict of cols/vals ect.

Comment: And I have the list of cols and indices which I gave to the API in the first place.

Comment: it may be more efficient to do string manipulations to get into valid json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to bulk load the data from the list of dicts and sort on the index column(s) afterwards. Pandas is optimized for this kind of thing.

First you need to adjust your list of tuples+dicts to be a list of dicts (so that you can initialize the dataframe easily) . One way (one-liner) to do that is this (assuming you have no control over how you parse them before and the format is as in your example):

```
your_data = [(2,{"col1":2,"col2":3}),(-1,{"col3":22,"col1":4})]
dict = [x[1].update({"idx_col":x[0]}) or x[1] for x in your_data]
dict>> [{'col1': 2, 'col2': 3, 'idx_col': 2}, {'col1': 4, 'col3': 22, 'idx_col': -1}]
```

Then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2","col3"]) #not necessary if every col appears 
#at least once in the data
df = df.append([{"idx_col":2,"col1":2,"col2":3},{"idx_col":-1,"col3":22,"col1":4}])     
#column order preserved

df = df.set_index("idx_col",drop=True).sort() #index order preserved now
```

Resulting df:

```
         col1  col2  col3
idx_col                  
-1          4   NaN    22
 2          2     3   NaN
```

If you have multiple index columns just use an array ["idx0","idx1",...] in the set_index method (although your example leads me to believe there is one index)

Comment: This is interesting and I've been playing around with it.  I'm trying to understand the speed concerns here.  I'm worried about what goes on behind the scenes with the multiple appends is slow.  Would this be faster than populating a dict[col_name][index_name] and than using reindex after a from_dict?

Comment: you can also initialize the data frame with the list of dicts  without calling append, ie df = pd.DataFrame([dict1,dict2,...]) but I think there is no performance difference.